# JsPlumb doesn't make connections when using non-default instance

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I'm going to use separate instances of jsPlumb for each canvas.
I'm using new features like Continious anchors and StateMachine connectors.
But I face the following issues:

- First of all, I initiate new instances with specific defaults,  and do not see them being applied.
- Secondary, the connection is not established on drop. I thought scope is the reason of an issues, but no.

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/CjBdX/34/, where you can reproduce issues stated above. (Please click initiate anchor before using demo) When using only one _default jsPlumbInstance, everything seems to work fine.

Please help me find a reason this code does not work.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to project author, Simon Porritt, all bugs wich led to my issues are now fixed in the latest version.
Thank you very much!